# JTable, How to set different side borders

Tags: java, swing, jtable, components, border

In my project i need to draw a facility plan.

I need to draw table made from squares and i tought i can make it with JTable component.

But there is one more thing i need:
I need to set different borders every cell but also i need to draw border to different sides of cells.

Here are my questions:

Is there any way to process every cell different?
Is there any component to do this?
Or is there any options to do, without jtable?

thank you so much.
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Table Row Rendering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/). It gives an example of how you might customize the Border for all cells in a row. You should be able to customize for your exact requirement.